# Shader for 1-bit color palette + a VFX ramp

Tags: unity3d, hlsl, shaders

I'm making a Unity game with a "1-bit" color palette, a la [Downwell](https://store.steampowered.com/app/360740/Downwell/) - the vast majority of the screen will end up being in black and white, but unlike true 1-bit graphics, some highlights and visual effects will use additional colors. In my case, those effects will output values along a range of colors making up a single color ramp - all the colors between green and pink inclusive, by default. It's also a low resolution, large-pixel game, and uses the [pixel perfect camera](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.pixel-perfect@1.0/manual/index.html) package to enforce that.

I want to be able to switch out the exact black, white, and color ramp values that are used at runtime, the same way that Downwell does through the ability to unlock additional palettes. That seems like a good job for shaders, so I finally buckled down and wrote some shader code for this. Now I want to check for room for improvement in terms of potential performance bottlenecks or general shader style.

This component is attached to the main camera:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ColorPaletteApplier : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material Material;

    void OnRenderImage (RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
    {
        Graphics.Blit(source, destination, Material);
    }
}
```

And this is the shader that I wrote:

```
Shader "Color Palette"
{
    Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _BlackColor ("Black Color", Color) = (0, 0, 0, 1)
        _WhiteColor ("White Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        _RampTex ("Ramp LUT", 2D) = "defaulttexture" {}
    }

    SubShader
    {
        // No culling or depth
        Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex, _RampTex;
            float4 _BlackColor, _WhiteColor;

            inline fixed4 convertBlackAndWhite (fixed4 input)
            {
                bool closerToWhite = round(input.r);
                return closerToWhite ? _WhiteColor : _BlackColor;
            }

            // input is assumed to be somewhere on a lerp between (0, 1, 0) and (1, 1, 0)
            // these colors are chosen so that one channel goes from 0 to 1, the other two channels are always the same value, and all three channels are never equal
            inline fixed4 convertEffectRamp (fixed4 input)
            {
                float i = input.r;
                
                // for effect pixels that break the g or b assumptions, we can assume they occupy subpixel positions and that the pixel perfect camera averaged their true value with the background pixel. we'll fix that by making the effects override the background color
                if (input.g == 0.5)
                {
                    // undo average with black
                    i *= 2;
                }
                else if (input.b == 0.5)
                {
                    // undo average with white
                    i = i * 2 - 1;
                }

                return tex2D(_RampTex, i);
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);

                return (col.r == col.g && col.g == col.b) ? convertBlackAndWhite(col) : convertEffectRamp(col);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a 128x1 PNG for the ramp lookup texture.